# getting input/output error from NFS client on RHEL5

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs

I have two RHEL5 boxes on a private network together (192.168.2.0/24) and I am trying to export a file system from one to the other but I keep getting the following error:

```
mount.nfs: Input/output error
```

on the client side I see this output:

```
mount: trying 192.168.2.101 prog 100003 vers 3 prot tcp port 2049
mount: trying 192.168.2.101 prog 100005 vers 3 prot tcp port 960
```

and on the server side I see this:

```
Sep 20 14:14:32 omicron mountd[18739]: authenticated mount request from 192.168.2.87:635 for /srv/nfs/web (/srv/nfs/web)
```

but that's all.  I opened up iptables so that the whole 192.168.2.0/24 network is allowed to communicate freely but the public side is locked down to 22,80 etc....

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, please have a look at this [link](http://pario.no/2008/01/15/allow-nfs-through-iptables-on-a-redhat-system/).
And [this one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-fedora-rhel-iptables-open-nfs-server-ports/).

Basically you have to open much more ports.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure portmapper is running

On centos

```
chkconfig --list | grep portmap
```

To start it on centos and set it to start at boot

```
service portmap start
chkconfig portmap on
```

Answer (score 1):

For a similar problem, I have added to the syntax of the mount command the following options "-o nolock, udp."

```
mount -o nolock,udp 192.168.4.11:/var/nfs /mnt/nfs/
```

Apparently this problem when the service nfslook is not 'started' successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- On the server, can you read/write to and from /srv/nfs/web?
- What's in your /etc/exports?
- What's in /etc/hosts.*
- What's in your /etc/sysconfig/iptables?
- What happens if you service iptables stop on both hosts and then try to mount it?
- The directory where you're trying to mount it you have read/write access to?
- What mount options are you using/what is the line in /etc/fstab for the mount?
- What is the output from 'showmount -a' and 'showmount -e'?

Comment: That should be in the comments, not in the answers.

Answer (score -1):

Please also note portsentry maybe running, disable it and restart portmap

```
# /etc/init.d/portmap status
portmap dead but subsys locked
# /etc/init.d/portsentry stop
chkconfig portsentry off
# /etc/init.d/portmap start     
Starting portmap:                                          [  OK  ]
```